# How to set resources for Docker containers in Gitlab runner

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I have configured a Gitlab runner and chosen Docker as the executor. Is there a way we can set resource limits for the containers in config.toml?

Currently the resources are not defined in config.toml and how can I specify the resources section in it? I'm planning to add CPU and Memory resources.

config.toml

```
concurrent = 5
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Test"
  url = "some-url"
  id = 10602
  output_limit = 10000
  token = "some token"
  token_obtained_at = some date
  token_expires_at = something
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "node:15"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Comment: In short yes. Is there a specific resource you wanted to limit and weren't able to? Which resource type was it? What was the limit you were aiming for and what its default? E.g., is your setting missing (or weren't you able to locate it) in the [The `[runners.docker]` section](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section)? Please add a bit more information to your question so that the context of your question becomes more clear and also it is more visible what you've done so far, e.g. your `config.toml` file.  Please [edit]. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited now and the resources are not set in config.toml

Comment: But here I don't see any parameter for resources mentioned here https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section

Comment: Thanks, but could you do me another favor and show your config.toml in the question you have so far (redact non-public information with exemplary values) especially as it does not work for you yet? And perhaps the operating system you're using?

Comment: `I don't see any parameter for resources` You don't? Like `cpu_shares` and `cpu` and `memory`?

Comment: Yes, and if the `config.toml` would be [edit]ed in finally we could even see if they are already part or not so the level of understanding and asking actually be clear and we could come towards an answerable question @KamilCuk But there seems to be a magic requirement to hide things to give the question a spicy touch of mystery.

Comment: Added the config.toml now

Comment: So I can directly set the resource limits in runners.docker section?